How to insert data into nested fields in groups
I'm trying to insert a value into a group of fields in an acf array from another post entry.
$post_field = get_fields($id);

$result = wp_insert_post([
    "post_type"   => "institution",
    "post_title"  => get_post($id)->post_title,
    "post_status" => "publish",
    "meta_input"  => [
        "author"       => $post_field["author"],
        "primary_info" => $post_field["primary_info"],
    ],
]);

Here $post_field['primary_info'] is an array:
$post_field["primary_info"] = [
    "full_name" => "name",
    "short_name" => "short_name",
];

And in the post type "institutes" - a group of nested fields.
A new post entry is created in the institutes, but only the "author" field is filled in, and the "primary information" field group remains empty.
'meta_input' => array(
    'author'                  => $post_field['author'],
    'primary_info_full_name'  => 'name'
),

This solved the problem, however I have a lot of fields in the group, so it is inconvenient

I can't speak to your specific problem, however I would encourage you to use ACF's specific methods for this such as update_field. These functions are very helpful and less error prone, especially as you get into deeper nesting, flexible layouts and other complex objects.
